# pysox under Windows

Tags: python, windows, building, sox

I am writing an application using Python with PyQT4 bindings, which should be multiplatform.
The version of Python I'm using is 3.3.
I fail to build pysox (SoX bindings for Python) under MS WindowsXP, although, step by step, I have managed to:
- compile Sox 14.4.1 from sources, using VC++ 10.0 Express.
- compile Cython to compile pysox.
Right now it fails to build, saying that strings.h is not found (if I plase SoX sources alonside with libsox.lib into the corresponding directory for pysox), then - something else not found, etc.
To be short, it fails to compile because it continues asking for Linux-specific headers, which I don't need right now, because I am under Windows.

The question is, is it possible to compile pysox under Windows AT ALL? Or I should rather compile it under Linux and then import the compiled libraries to Windows, because Python is multiplatform?

Comment: Since you have a working Sox, have you tried just installing pysox from pip?

Comment: Is it possible to do it on Windows? Do I need Cygwin?

Comment: I wouldn't know. As I said, I'd just try installing pysox through pip and see what happens.

Comment: Installing through pip also requires compilation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To everyone reading this and banging their heads into the wall:
**Don't bother.**
I'm not saying it is not possible, but when it's not easy, just make an easier solution.
Sox is a command line tool. There is the latest Windows version already compiled for you, so you absolutely don't need `pysox`.
Here is a Python 3 example how to use `sox.exe`, provided it is distributed with your application and is in the same folder:

```
    command = """sox.exe "{0}" """.format(FilePath)
    startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    sox = subprocess.Popen(command, startupinfo = startupinfo)
```

You won't see any popup, there will be little to no delay, you can implement callback functions if you really need to.
Here is the full list of available commands:
http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html

The only bad thing is that it is not possible to send `Ctrl+C` command to sox.exe as a subprocess to stop recording, for instance. Thus, I've ended up using `pyaudio` for recording and `sox.exe` for converting `.wav` to `.ogg` with specific parameters.